# How can I reduce the number of digits after decimal point when writing floats to file?

Tags: python

In my program I am printing float numbers to file. There is high precision of these numbers so there are many digits after decimal point, i.e number 0.0433896882981. How can I reduce number of digits that I print into file? So I would print, say, 0.043 instead of 0.0433896882981.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use basic string formatting, such as:

```
>>> print '%.4f' % (2.2352341234)
2.2352
```

Here, the `%.4f` tells Python to limit the precision to four decimal places.

Comment: Can `.4` provided as a variable?

Comment: @alper The documentation for [this style of string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) describes how to do this. See the description for "precision".

Answer (score 8):

You don't say which version, or really how you are doing it in, so I'm going to assume 3.x.

```
str.format("{0:.3f}", pi) # use 3 digits of precision and float-formatting.
```

The format specifier generally looks like this:

> [[fill]align][sign][#][0][minimumwidth][.precision][type]

Other examples:

```
>>> str.format("{0:" ">10.5f}", 3.14159265)
'   3.14159'
>>> str.format("{0:0>10.5f}", 3.14159265)
'0003.14159'
>>> str.format("{0:<10.5f}", 3.14159265)
'3.14159   '
```

Comment: You should really use the string method rather than the `str` method: `"{0:.3f}".format(pi)`. And lose the semicolon!

Comment: The semicolons creep in all the time when I do Python. It's unavoidable :D

Answer (score 3):

The number of digits after the decimal point can be specified with the following formatting directive below:

```
In [15]: n = 0.0433896882981
In [16]: print '%.3f' % n
```

that yields:

```
0.043
```

The `%  f` part indicates that you are printing a number with a decimal point, the `.3` the numbers of digits after the decimal point.

Additional examples:

```
In [17]: print '%.1f' % n
0.0

In [18]: print '%.2f' % n
0.04

In [19]: print '%.4f' % n
0.0434

In [20]: print '%.5f' % n
0.04339
```